# Collection Initializer adding items in wrong order within linq select

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to get a list of lists from an IQueryable object. Table looks something like

```
prop_A | prop_B | sort_order
   A   | Apple  |     1
   B   |  Bat   |     2
   C   | Crane  |     3
```

This works perfectly

```
db.table.Select(x => new List<string>() { x.prop_a, x.prop_b}).ToList();
```

returns `[[A, Apple], [B, Bat], [C, Crane]]`

But as soon as I throw in an orderby clause

```
db.table.OrderBy(x => x.sort_order).Select(x => new List<string>() { x.prop_a, x.prop_b}).ToList();
```

the order of the inner lists is seemingly random. e.g. `[[A, Apple], [Bat, B], [Crane, C]]`

Does anyone know why this is, and what I can do to fix it?

**EDIT**

Like mentioned below, my issue is that IQueryable objects are not sorted. I ended up doing this in two steps.

```
var foo = db.table.OrderBy(x => x.sort_order).AsEnumerable();
var bar = foo.Select(x => new List<string>() { x.prop_a, x.prop_b}).ToList();
```

Comment: Rather than editing your answer into the question, you should post your answer *as an answer*.  Also, you can use `AsEnumerable` rather than `ToList` to accomplish the same thing without all of the wasted overhead of populating a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do Select on a IQueryable, the order is not preserved. If you do Select on an IEnumerable, then order is preserved.

**Edit**

It doesn't matter in which order the OrderBy and Select are called.

Comment: **Both** selects are performed on IQueryables.  **Neither** of them is performed on an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Due to sort_order being an int and the select being a list of strings, putting the OrderBy at the end was more trouble than it was worth. But this pointed me in the right direction. See my edit for what I ended up doing.

Comment: What kind of troubles gave you? I don't see why it should

Comment: @Servy You are actually correct. They both are IQueryable. I removed the part of my answer that implied putting the orderby at the end would make it be performed on an IQueryable.

Comment: @CavynVonDeylen This answer is not correct.  It is incorrectly claiming that the order that these two operations are called in matters.  It does not matter.  Please do not mark an incorrect answer as the answer to the question, you'll only mislead future readers.

Comment: Although my original answer didn't come outright and say that putting the OrderBy at the end would cause it to be performed on an IEnumerable, the wording was misleading. I edited it to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the OrderBy with the field you want to sort by at the end.

As an example, if you want to sort by prop_a, try the following:

```
db.table.Select(x => new List<string>() { x.prop_a, x.prop_b}).OrderBy(x => x.prop_a).ToList();
```

EDIT: As confirmed, db is type of IQueryable. This type does not preserve the order and the OrderBy should be at the end in this case

Comment: It should be irrelevant which order these two methods are called in.

Comment: @lpaloub In response to your comment, I tried adding the `sort_order` column into the select clause, but LINQ to Entities was having troubles converting it to a string, or even an object (it's an int). Also after selecting into the string list, the property names are no longer available so you need to use indices to get the fields in the orderby, which I thought looked messy.

Comment: What about not puting the int in the select list, just in the OrderBy? Does this work?

Comment: @lpaloub No, it looks like when you put the OrderBy after the Select, the OrderBy only has access to the properties specifically chosen in the Select clause.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your case with the following code in debug mode, and everything is working as desired. Nothing exceptional.

```
var items = new List<Item>
                {
                    new Item
                        {
                            prop_a = "A", prop_b = "Apple", sort_order = 1
                        }, new Item
                               {
                                   prop_a = "B", prop_b = "Bat", sort_order = 2
                               }, new Item
                                      {
                                          prop_a = "C", prop_b = "Crane", sort_order = 3
                                      },
                };

var list1 = items.Select(x => new List<string> {x.prop_a, x.prop_b}).ToList();
var list2 = items.OrderBy(x => x.sort_order).Select(x => new List<string> {x.prop_a, x.prop_b}).ToList();
```

And the `Item` class is below:

```
public class Item
{
    public string prop_a { get; set; }
    public string prop_b { get; set; }
    public int sort_order { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Like @clhereistian said, his db object is probably not a List item, so it does not preserver the order